# Pulling and placing a href with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to pull the `a href` from a dynamic link and inserting the `a href` src into another link.

An extract from my HTML code:

```
<li id="source_ahref"><a href="http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?p=4729682#post4729682">This is the Source Link</a></li>
<li class="text">Support Document 4&nbsp;<a id="target_ahref" href="#">Read Document</a></li>
```

My Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var theHref = $("#source_ahref a:first").attr("href");
  $("#target_ahref a:first").attr("href", theHref);
</script>
```

You can see my complete code at http://jsfiddle.net/prodac/Azr7K/

Thank you! :)

Comment: I finally managed to put a working solution together. A big thanks to everybody! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chinmayee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076679/pulling-and-placing-ahref-with-jquery/4076701#4076701), following the update, is not correct any more. Assuming that you're HTML structure looks like that in your question, with each `li` element next to each other, then you can use this instead:

```
$('.target_ahref').attr('href', function(){
    return $(this).parent().prev().children('a').attr('href');
});
```

Depending on your situation, you might also want use this selector for the return statement:

```
return $(this).parent().prevAll('.source_ahref').first().children('a').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 4):

Small correction,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var theHref = $("#source_ahref a:first").attr("href");
  $("#target_ahref").attr("href", theHref);
</script>
```

**#target_ahref is sufficient as it is id of anchor tag**

Assuming your id is your class [as per below comments], here is updated code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $.each($(".source_ahref"),function(){
         var theHref = $("a:first",$(this)).attr("href");
         $(".target_ahref",$(this).parent()).attr("href", theHref);
     });
</script>
```

Comment: In your code, you have repeated same id in each UL tag which is not a good thing. You should always use unique id for your elements.

Comment: In my final doc I'm using a dynamically created ID.

Comment: I have updated my code with your suggestion, but I can't get that to work either. Please find an updated version at http://jsfiddle.net/prodac/qvBn2/

Comment: Just change $(".target_ahref",$(this)).attr("href", theHref);
 to $(".target_ahref",$(this).parent()).attr("href", theHref); as $(this) returns li and our target anchor tag is in another li, we have to find it in UL i.e. parent of source li.

Answer (score 0):

Replace $("#target_ahref a:first").attr("href", theHref); with the following:

```
$("#target_ahref").attr("href", theHref);
```

Coz your #target_ahref is actually the a itself, so it is not needed to refer to the a:first.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to put a working solution together. A big thanks to everybody! :)

The code can be viewed at http://jsfiddle.net/prodac/qvBn2/. Feel free to use and edit a!